# Spivak's Calculus, Ch 11, problem 24: describe the graph of a rational function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Spivak, Chapter 11 "Significance of the Derivative", problem 24

> 24. Describe the graph of a rational function (in very general terms, similar to the text's description of the graph of a polynomial
>     function).

Let $f(x)=\frac{r(x)}{s(x)}$ for polynomial functions $r$ and $s$.

If $r$ and $s$ have a common root $a$ with multiplicity 1, then these polynomials have a common factor $x-a$. For $x \neq a$ we can cancel these factors and we are left with another rational function $g(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}=\frac{a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_0}{b_mx^m+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+...+b_0}$, where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ have no common roots.

$g(x)$ is not defined at roots of $q(x)$, and roots of $p(x)$ are roots of $g(x)$. At roots of $q(x)$ the graph of $g(x)$ has a vertical asymptote.

What happens to the graph of $g$ at common roots of $r$ and $s$?

If the common root has multiplicity 1 as described above, it seems that what happens is that $f$ is undefined at these points but the graph isn't a vertical asymptote.

Here is an example

$$f(x)=\frac{(x-1) \cdot x}{(x-1)\cdot x^2} \implies \lim\limits_{x \to 1} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{x} = 1$$

Since the common root isn't a root of $p$ or $q$ (because it has multiplicity 1 in $r$ and $s$), we know that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)=\frac{p(a)}{q(a)}$

In the following example, 1 is a root of $r(x)$ with multiplicity 2.
$$g(x)=\frac{(x-1)^2 \cdot x}{(x-1) \cdot x^2} =\frac{x-1}{x-1} \cdot \frac{(x-1)\cdot x}{x^2} \implies \lim\limits_{x \to 1} g(x)= \lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{x-1}{x}=0
$$

Therefore 1 is also a root of $p$. Hence $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x) = 0$

In the example below, now 1 is a root of $s$ with multiplicity 2. It is also a root of $q$ (but not $p$). Hence we get the vertical asymptote.

$$g(x)=\frac{(x-1) \cdot x}{(x-1)^2 \cdot x^2} \implies \lim\limits_{x \to 1} g(x)= \lim\limits_{x \to 1} \frac{1}{(x-1) \cdot x}=\infty
$$

In summary, for a root $a$ common to $r$ and $s$ (including common multiplicity), $f$ is not defined at $a$, but the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=\frac{p(a)}{q(a)}$ .

If the multiplicity of the common root is larger in the numerator, then $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=0$, if it is larger in the denominator then we have a vertical asymptote.

Are there any more cases?